# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Base64 encoded data URIs for images?

Tags: images, load-time, data, background-image, data-uri

I have been seeing people using base64 encoding on a few small icons and styles, but nothing too important like the content itself.

I was wondering, is there an advantage to using base64 over a .png file?
Is loading a base64 image faster than loading the image in a .png or .gif?
Does this effect SEO in a bad way?

My assumption is that it won't effect SEO as long as its an image asset to design such as favicon or css background tile.
What are the best practices and is this something I should integrate on my websites?

Comment: I should have searched before I wrote an answer, I found a duplicate: [Image data URI and SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56701/image-data-uri-and-seo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I thought I searched for base64 but couldn't find anything