# Why do some web pages bake images into their HTML?

Tags: html, images, inlining

Some webpages bake image data into the HTML, like [this one](https://www.automobilemag.com/news/1994-ford-power-stroke-concept-truck-history/) which has baked it into a piece JavaScript code, making the size of the HTML document itself reach several MB in size. Why do some web developers choose to do that? What are the benefits?

Comment: See also: [Image data URI and SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56701/image-data-uri-and-seo)

Answer (score 12):

There is a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6819314/).

What you are seeing is referred to as a `data URI scheme` but some just call it a base64 encoded image. The main benefit can be page speed but there are various reasons (shown below) as to when it's more appropriate.

> According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Advantages):
>
> **Advantages**:
>
> - HTTP request and header traffic is not required for embedded data, so    data URIs consume less bandwidth whenever the overhead of
>   encoding    the inline content as a data URI is smaller than the HTTP
>   overhead.    For example, the required base64 encoding for an image
>   600 bytes long    would be 800 bytes, so if an HTTP request required
>   more than 200    bytes of overhead, the data URI would be more
>   efficient.
> - For transferring many small files (less than a few kilobytes each), this can be faster. TCP transfers tend to start slowly. If each file
>   requires a new TCP connection, the transfer speed is limited by the
>   round-trip time rather than the available bandwidth. Using HTTP
>   keep-alive improves the situation, but may not entirely alleviate the
>   bottleneck.
> - When browsing a secure HTTPS web site, web browsers commonly require that all elements of a web page be downloaded over secure
>   connections, or the user will be notified of reduced security due to a
>   mixture of secure and insecure elements. On badly configured servers,
>   HTTPS requests have significant overhead over common HTTP requests, so
>   embedding data in data URIs may improve speed in this case.
> - Web browsers are usually configured to make only a certain number    (often two) of concurrent HTTP connections to a domain, so inline
>   data frees up a download connection for other content.
> - Environments with limited or restricted access to external resources    may embed content when it is disallowed or impractical to
>   reference    it externally. For example, an advanced HTML editing
>   field could    accept a pasted or inserted image and convert it to a
>   data URI to    hide the complexity of external resources from the
>   user.    Alternatively, a browser can convert (encode) image based
>   data from    the clipboard to a data URI and paste it in a HTML
>   editing field.    Mozilla Firefox 4 supports this functionality.
> - It is possible to manage a multimedia page as a single file. Email    message templates can contain images (for backgrounds or signatures)
>   without the image appearing to be an "attachment".
>
> **Disadvantages**:
>
> - Data URIs are not separately cached from their containing documents    (e.g. CSS or HTML files) so data is downloaded every time the
>   containing documents are redownloaded. Content must be re-encoded and
>   re-embedded every time a change is made.
> - Internet Explorer through version 7 (approximately 15% of the market as of January 2011), lacks support. However this can be
>   overcome by serving browser specific content.
>   Internet Explorer 8 limits data URIs to a maximum length of 32 KB.
> - Data is included as a simple stream, and many processing environments (such as web browsers) may not support using containers
>   (such as multipart/alternative or message/rfc822) to provide greater
>   complexity such as metadata, data compression, or content negotiation.
> - Base64-encoded data URIs are 1/3 larger in size than their binary    equivalent. (However, this overhead is reduced to 2-3% if the HTTP
>   server compresses the response using gzip) Data URIs make it more
>   difficult for security software to filter content.
>
> According to [other
> sources](http://www.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/)
>
> - Data URLs are significantly slower on mobile browsers.

[Credit to Shaz for his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6819412/2268476)

Comment: `Internet Explorer through version 7 (approximately 15% of the market as of January 2011)` - is that... relevant today?

Comment: Another advantage is that if everything is contained in a single file, a "Save As..." will produce a simple local copy of the page that can be easily transferred as a single unit via USB drive or other means, and can be moved around without having to also drag around a directory of supplemental files to go with it.

Comment: Additional drawback that ties in with the caching bullet point but is also a broader separate issue: the image is not (easily) re-usable on another page. I.e. a company logo that occurs on each page will be downloaded with each page instead of once initially.